# Why does null model randomization function not generate combinations to original dataset (in R)?

Tags: r, function, null, combinations, correlation

Dataset with two species with measured parameters `x` and `v`, used to compute `fun` as shown below. I'm interested in the relationship between `x` and `fun`. First, I plot a simple regression and calculation correlation. Slope and correlations close to zero for `A` and positive for `B`.

```
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(sp = rep(c("A","B"), each = 72),
                x = c(4.09083761610187,5.17658523329813,88.6562224027959,2.25836477635251,0,0,1.70314566646874,11.3987297349982,1.84003114057151,0.457347550869641,6.70486507447813,48.6677505892291,0.350833121700547,15.8838267048794,5.49806107817606,4.19614169775253,0,27.9447266500485,161.40528316833,65.206626868528,229.977300293161,80.5368571263762,0.8070257021242,44.5220539542662,26.7971708355538,18.9939168599581,42.9711176078836,223.592234760637,2.66598123235831,75.3845184719839,229.044409727423,16.3551314594714,35.4832280206832,14.5498902625194,0,96.887175263674,8.99396566505568,23.3706346405744,47.8941849732038,44.3451732332786,0,12.011297608005,56.6164316620521,24.1342520786029,25.5272703059762,16.7003554201212,3.5707173176337,11.8552761027447,109.662475067734,3.18511558991655,165.507847224063,25.8925659104313,0,7.07535776285528,128.766259891874,6.1903777215754,16.0177727282558,17.1843838213112,0,4.68918800125815,0,0,5.35341932612548,0,0,0,4.79811034830547,9.79829373980636,0.586790696303578,23.19506575785,0,0,2.49109587550093,3.0037582153087,2.7346389424851,1.08984306462015,0.693785502377993,6.96926357190652,0.240712701491344,0.445114076731931,1.41358924176887,7.44157458706162,14.1532491980006,39.4545181653573,7.10832955559845,1.58644035716805,6.09408111393482,2.13790515926047,15.8397891326159,24.0133144987896,1.74160611325828,5.75465739960016,3.2758777828907,4.34621775864299,36.6021226483913,42.9406719427144,72.6822936095161,3.72898903362054,3.67552027919314,13.1296071525939,34.1045568903693,16.3363883520053,31.5827615348977,5.97666434550248,62.192418782429,31.09097713574,69.2007581730322,44.470881685922,2.92939829967541,3.30158453410897,4.72251518968395,5.43846334761562,3.5647110602072,20.345805572489,12.7637440618043,3.24361390997942,18.3004215648496,6.76278398428486,20.9230830406293,26.9222404057172,11.5464425137739,3.68528616294467,4.05311133278512,17.8463031680537,3.44197693707345,7.56542957655526,2.48488433485702,2.28137328268173,2.97003477893868,6.70097331584508,13.311763906039,5.52645451307264,2.01923891621468,3.02398209355209,2.38972819838365,2.55487984211681,0.552853459267435,1.36420461604884,7.97413740851264,3.33574934430844,3.22201093384178,2.61395174373814,5.58938217966659,1.76573739787898),
                v = c(46.9714663467755,107.188138710401,11684.6098516062,10.6665841084123,0,0,1.18831866391101,466.408805714305,6.71795646324421,0.836667129145835,157.941707195036,202.582073492942,0.492335517128602,631.789498751021,45.8120447754732,70.43042059047,0,1050.46296482415,34133.1113157904,5354.31049016579,59749.5996923197,10307.8112423707,2.60516193555623,1250.51516983849,2038.42025545643,817.715450258589,3283.67363691491,193951.535557093,28.4298237251469,16569.7968377392,154978.503636124,806.776623624088,3935.89731000162,198.929334760752,0,27941.9729751578,136.938274422669,1387.00467143898,2509.73033829852,2796.10679221937,0,267.824301581129,3825.56480335201,874.245394428681,992.361147124208,479.473000918125,51.0000886497969,82.3841098380795,15972.4192502092,40.5798452845178,96984.1848416804,2681.69987770411,0,26.3000143374392,47478.4961053446,153.283105343108,772.694384900138,829.429597576107,0,17.2018962765564,0,0,114.636393925335,0,0,0,57.1219477165072,65.59322089856,1.37729328507375,2031.25007525489,0,0,0.120457150497474,2.46352262738759,0.172459020975522,2.40251376644104,0.735669717407467,93.8141949284959,0.231770418637043,0.298439882291242,0.56857681602162,135.574480542324,174.344413723302,581.100881838344,92.8498441343021,0.204256498577018,51.8285867856588,0.0902049419545885,304.221203347947,1533.97614074233,0.186513812264599,50.86771298888,0.901593836251441,5.64635027963072,712.636841896461,1600.64248319816,6619.05913063679,1.36434006762406,1.46160907834462,138.452541607182,1220.77019361911,546.188215442208,1533.06442893318,28.8912291484039,14067.1539618199,3007.83042162745,7751.54365187716,2532.24493148154,2.10473856352353,0.242416509799162,3.25446131927778,9.43846066122247,0.181266143326679,516.742874607795,152.208733652681,3.29707163679978,187.571468231534,15.3282470249977,1274.09360804198,613.166120285965,307.306613761453,0.940093352820059,1.92826204528546,716.979024988641,0.543524786525445,104.352845868818,1.38884037014775,1.48297639496721,0.420886459199868,59.573933770932,481.509594462794,28.161731965957,0.213366244193053,1.13544416067409,3.20964573483893,0.543045443597935,0.496360723857252,0.674057448254231,92.977653772693,1.67111964170586,1.08098471493858,0.619195597090877,50.244417888853,0.192030655860555)
                )

df$fun <- ((df$v/df$x^2) - (1/(df$x)))
  
my.formula = y ~ x
ggplot(df, aes(y = (fun), x = x, color = sp)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color= sp))+ 
  facet_wrap(.~sp, scales = "free") +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = my.formula )  


A.cor <- cor(df[df$sp=="A",]$x, df[df$sp=="A",]$fun, use = "complete.obs")
B.cor <- cor(df[df$sp=="B",]$x, df[df$sp=="B",]$fun, use = "complete.obs")

\[enter image description here\](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIh9V.png)
```

Then, for each species I shuffle `v` in the dataset keep `x` the same. I compute `fun` 999 times. I compute the correlation for each instance. I store that in a data table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

f <- function(x, v) {
  v.sample <- sample(v, length(v), replace=FALSE)
  y.sample <- ((v.sample/x^2) - (1/x))
  per <- cor(y.sample, x, use="complete.obs")
  data.frame(v.sample = v.sample, y.sample = y.sample, rand.cor = per)
}

result <- rbindlist(
  lapply(split(df, df$sp), function(dat)
    rbindlist(
      lapply(1:999, function(i) dat[, .(f(x, v), x, v, sp, fun)][, i:=i])
    )
  )
)

result$cor.original <- ifelse(result$sp == "A", A.cor, B.cor)
```

Here, I plot a histogram of all correlations, mean expected correlation (blue libe), and observed correlation (black). I am surprised to find that there are no correlations that are positive. I ran this 9999 times as well, but I can't seem to find anything where the original dataset combination is sampled. Sure, there are 72^72 combinations, but it's suprising that no combination yielded positive values. I am wondering if there is something weird going on in my sampler function that I am missing out on?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3CLs.png)

```
ggplot(result, aes(x=rand.cor)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(color = sp)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(rand.cor)), color="blue", linetype="dashed", linewidth=1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = cor.original), color="black", linetype="dashed", linewidth=1) + 
  facet_grid(.~sp)
```